# CXF implementation of JAX-WS with JDK 1.5

Tags: cxf, java-5

When I googled, I found out the JAX-WS implementation is coming with JDK 1.6 rt.jar.

But I want to use JAX-WS CXF implementation with JDK 1.5.

I am not able to find the correct maven dependencies for this.

Can anyone share any good links regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

> - GroupId: com.sun.xml.ws
> - ArtifactId: jaxws-rt
> - Version: 2.1.3

[Source](https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/using_jax_ws_with_maven)

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following dependency on our POM file, I hope it would be enough.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
<artifactId>cxf-bundle</artifactId>
<version>2.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks!

Comment: With Java5, you would need to use version 2.6.13.   With CXF 2.7.x, we dropped support for Java5.